# How to receive a json string after a jquery post in WebMatrix?

Tags: json, jquery-post, asp.net-webpages

If I have the following post call:

```
 $('#json_form').submit(function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var datos = {
                "uno": "lalala",
                "dos": "jojojo"
            }
            var data = JSON.stringify(datos);

            $.post(url, data, function (resultado) {
                $('#posted_values').html(resultado);
            });
        });
```

How can I receive and process the json object in a cshtml file? I mean what I put in Decode call:

```
if (IsPost)
    {
        var json_object = Json.Decode(Request???);
}
```

---

**Edited to complete the answer of @MikeBrind**, to help others with the same problem.
Example of using decode for a more complex json object.

```
     $('#json_form').submit(function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var datos = {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Smith",
                "age": 25,
                "address": {
                    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
                    "city": "New York",
                    "state": "NY",
                    "postalCode": 10021
                },
                "phoneNumber": [
                    {
                        "type": "home",
                        "number": "212 555-1234"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "fax",
                        "number": "646 555-4567"
                    }
                ]
            }

            var data = JSON.stringify(datos);

            $.post(url, {"person": data}, function (resultado) {
                $('#posted_values').html(resultado);
            });
        });
```

Receiving and using:

```
@{
    dynamic json_object;    
    if (IsPost)
    {
        json_object = Json.Decode(Request["person"]);
        @json_object.firstName<br/>
        @json_object.lastName<br/>        
        @json_object.address.city<br/>
        @json_object.address.postalCode<br/>
        foreach (dynamic phone in json_object.phoneNumber)
        {
            @phone.type<br/>
            @phone.number
        }

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `JSON.stringify` the data if it is just key/value pairs like this. Do a form post:

```
$('#json_form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var datos = {
        "uno": "lalala",
        "dos": "jojojo"
    }
    //var data = JSON.stringify(datos); no need for this

    $.post(url, datos, function (resultado) {
        $('#posted_values').html(resultado);
    });
});
```

Then the values are available from `Request["uno"]` and `Request["dos"]`

If you ever do need to use `JSON.stringify` (which you would for more complex data structures), the JSON is transmitted in the Request body, so you need to extract it from `Request.InputStream`:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Excellent @Mike. I'm going to add code to the question showing this scenario using a Json object that i found in Wikipedia, I think it will be useful for other peoples.